# How to prevent SElinux from blocking custom systemd service at boot?

Tags: selinux, systemd-unit

SElinux is preventing a custom service of mine from getting picked up by systemd at boot.

> MESSAGE=SELinux is preventing systemd from read access on the file custom.service

##### before rebooting

```
[root@box opt]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@box opt]# systemctl enable --now custom
[root@box opt]# systemctl status custom.service
● custom.service - foo
   Loaded: loaded (/opt/foo/bar/systemd/custom.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-10-07 12:18:27 EDT; 1min 28s ago
...
...
```

##### after reboot

```
[root@box opt]# systemctl status custom.service
Unit custom.service could not be found.
```

So I disabled selinux and rebooted but it didn’t seem to help anything. I then changed the selinux user, role, and type of the service file and tried a reboot again.

```
[root@box opt]# chcon -R -u unconfined_u -r object_r -t systemd_unit_file_t foo/bar/systemd/
```

Still nothing... Then I noticed that the symlink I placed in `/etc/systemd/system` was showing a `?` for the secontext. The same thing happens if I `cp` the service file into the `/etc/systemd/system` directory too.

```
[root@box opt]# ls -Z /etc/systemd/system/custom.service
? /etc/systemd/system/custom.service
```

Anyone know what needs to be done here to fix this?

**TLDR** - SElinux is preventing systemd from reading an enabled custom systemd unit even though selinux is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I re-enabled selinux in permissive mode and my service was started after boot. I imagine the `chcon` command I ran didn't have any effect since selinux was disabled beforehand.

I have now disabled selinux and rebooted and everything seems to be working. Still don't quite understand why the secontext matters if selinux is disabled though.

```
# ls -Z now shows the correct context
[root@box ~]$ ls -Z /etc/systemd/system/custom.service
system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 /etc/systemd/system/custom.service
```